# App crashes when I click a Button if EditText is empty

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I wrote a simple temperature converter app, everything is working fine except when user leaves EditText blank/null but selects one of the radio buttons, The App crashes.

Here is the Kotlin Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var etTemp: EditText
    lateinit var radioGroup: RadioGroup
    lateinit var btnConverter :Button
    lateinit var tempConverted: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        title = "Zeeshan's Temperature Converter"

        etTemp = findViewById(R.id.etTemp)
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup)
        btnConverter = findViewById(R.id.btnConverter)
        tempConverted = findViewById(R.id.tempConverted)

        btnConverter.setOnClickListener {

            val id = radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
            val radioButton = findViewById<RadioButton>(id)

            if (radioButton == findViewById(R.id.radioC)){
                val temp =etTemp.text.toString().toInt()

                val result = temp * 9/5 + 32

                tempConverted.setText(result.toString())
            }
            else if (radioButton == findViewById(R.id.radioF)){
                val tempy =etTemp.text.toString().toInt()

                val resulty = (tempy - 32) / 1.8

                tempConverted.setText(resulty.toString())
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Select one conversion scale", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is "etTemp" is the variable that stays blank? and App crashes?

Comment: did you try reading the error messages on logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if etTemp.text.ToString() == "" (that is empty string) if it is, then do not try to convert it into int. The problem appears when you try to convert "null" value to int.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the listener add a check for for EditText to check whether it is empty or not,

```
btnConverter.setOnClickListener {

// Add the validation check here ... like this -> if(etTemp.length() > 0){

    val id = radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
    val radioButton = findViewById<RadioButton>(id)

    if (radioButton == findViewById(R.id.radioC)){
        val temp =etTemp.text.toString().toInt()

        val result = temp * 9/5 + 32

        tempConverted.setText(result.toString())
    }
    else if (radioButton == findViewById(R.id.radioF)){
        val tempy =etTemp.text.toString().toInt()

        val resulty = (tempy - 32) / 1.8

        tempConverted.setText(resulty.toString())
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Select one conversion scale", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
// Close the check here -> }
    else{
    //     Prompt the user to put some text in the field - this is called form validation before processing
    //     Toast.makeText(.....).show
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the user has entered some input or not, one way is like below (Kotlin):

```
if(!etTemp.text.isNullOrEmpty())
{
    temp =etTemp.text.toString().toInt()
}
```